# XSL transform is failing to return values with the XPathEntityProcessor in Solr

Tags: xml, debugging, xslt, solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to use the XSL option with the XpathEntityProcessor to select data from an xml transformation. The configuration runs without error, however it returns no values. At this point it would be a home-run just to get it to index one word from the **IUPAC entity** below. All of the other entities work as expected. I want to use the XSL option so that I can get full access to XPATH in order to make specific selections. the data is messy and will require further processing either with javascript or regex.

My entity looks like this.

```
    <document>
    <!-- this outer processor generates a list of files satisfying the conditions
         specified in the attributes -->
    <entity 
        name="f" 
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        fileName=".*xml"
        newerThan="'NOW-30YEARS'"
        recursive="true"
        rootEntity="false"
        dataSource="null"
        baseDir="C:\DrugLabels\Prescription\Test"
        transformer="RegexTransformer,TemplateTransformer">

    <!-- this strips the file extension and sets the id = the file name -->     
            <field column="file" regex="^(.*)/|.xml" replaceWith="$1" name="id"/>


    <!-- this processor extracts content using Xpath from each file found -->

        <entity 
        name="DrugLabel" 
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
        forEach="/document"
        url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}">

            <entity 
            name="document_title" 
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            transformer="script:lineToTitleCase"
            forEach="/document"
            url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}">

                <field column="title" xpath="/document/title"/>

            </entity>

            <entity 
            name="ingredients" 
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            transformer="script:listToTitleCase"
            forEach="/document"
            url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}">

                <field column="generic_medicine" xpath="/document/component/structuredBody/component/section/subject/manufacturedProduct/manufacturedProduct/asEntityWithGeneric/genericMedicine/name"/></entity>

            </entity>

            <entity 
            name="IUPAC" 
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            transformer="RegexTransformer, script:debug"
            forEach="/add"
            url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}"
            xsl="C:\solr-4.3.1\example\solr\DrugLabels\conf\section-description-transform.xsl">

                <field column="chemical_name" xpath="/add/doc/field/@chemical_name" flatten="true"/>

            </entity>
        </entity>                       
    </entity>
</document>
```

The transformation file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <add>
                <doc>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/document">
                        <field name="chemical_name"><xsl:value-of select="/document/component/structuredBody/component/section/text/paragraph"/></field>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </doc>
            </add>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The debug script:

```
function debug(row) {
    var r = row.get('chemical_name').toString;
    r = 'value: ' + r;
    row.put('chemical_name', r);
    return row;
}
```

And the output:

```
"chemical_name": [
    "value: function toString() {/*\njava.lang.String toString()\n*/}\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <add>
        <xsl:for-each select="document/entity">
            <doc>
                <xsl:for-each select=".//field">
                    <field name="{@column}"><xsl:value-of select="@xpath"/></field>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </doc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </add>
</xsl:template>
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082988/) which may help as well.